# max() value from a nested select without ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, nested, subquery

this question I've found is driving me nuts, (edit:) because I'm trying to achieve this without the order by method. 
I have a table:

**BookAuthors**(book, author)

```
book     author
------ ---------
1        Joy McBean
2        Marti McFly
2        Joahnn Strauss
2        Steven Spoilberg
1        Quentin Toronto
3        Dr E. Brown
```

both, book and author, are keys.

Now I would like to select the 'book' value with highest number of different 'author', and the number of authors.
In our case, the query should retrieve the 'book' 2 with a number of 3 authors.

```
book        authors
-------- ------------
2            3
```

I've been able to group them and obtain the number of authors for each book with this query:

```
select B.book, count(B.author) as authors
from BookAuthors B
group by B.book
```

which will results in:

```
book        authors
-------- -------------
1              2
2              3
3              1
```

Now I would like to obtain only the book with the highest number of authors.
This is one of the queries I've tried:

```
select Na.libro, Na.authors from (
    select B.book, count(B.author) as authors
    from BookAuthors B
    group by B.book
    ) as Na
where Na.authors in (select max(authors) from Na)
```

and

```
select Na.libro, Na.authors from (
    select B.book, count(B.author) as authors
    from BookAuthors B
    group by B.book
    ) as Na
having max( Na.authors)
```

I'm a little bit struggled...

Thank you for your help.

EDIT:
since @Sebas was kind to reply right AND expanding my question, here is the solution come to my mind using the CREATE VIEW method:

```
create view auth as
    select A.book, count(A.author)
    from BooksAuthors A
    group by A.book
;
```

and then

```
select B.book, B.nAuthors
from auth B 
where B.nAuthors = (select max(nAuthors)
                    from auth)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT cnt.book, maxauth.mx
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(authors) as mx
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT book, COUNT(author) AS authors 
            FROM BookAuthors 
            GROUP BY book
        ) t
    ) maxauth JOIN 
        (
            SELECT book, COUNT(author) AS authors 
            FROM BookAuthors 
            GROUP BY book
        ) cnt ON cnt.authors = maxauth.mx
```

This solution would be more beautiful and efficient with a view:

```
CREATE VIEW v_book_author_count AS 
    SELECT book, COUNT(author) AS authors 
    FROM BookAuthors 
    GROUP BY book
;
```

and then:

```
SELECT cnt.book, maxauth.mx
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(authors) as mx
    FROM v_book_author_count 
    ) maxauth JOIN v_book_author_count AS cnt ON cnt.authors = maxauth.mx
;
```

Comment: Hi! It's not for the purpose of the question, but I'm curious to see it now!

Comment: b.book is not defined anyway

Comment: You've just forget to refer the 3rd level select (which retrieve an error on mySql), but it's a really good answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Edoardoo adding the view option

Comment: I've just added another version of CREATE VIEW implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
select book, max(authors)
from ( select B.book, count(B.author) as authors 
    from BookAuthors B group by B.book ) 
table1;
```

I could not try this as i dont have mysql with me... You try and let me know...

Comment: **table1** is the alias name given to the derived table.

Comment: ok, this will select the first book and the max value of authors, not necessary related to the book.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong answer. I tried the query and the result came out exactly as you said. The solution i found was close to what @Sebas has written in the first part of his answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT book b, COUNT(author) c 
FROM BookAuthors
GROUP BY b
ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I've edited the question adding the 'no order by ' constraint, since it is very expensive in terms of resources (it needs to order the whole table first)

Comment: even with "LIMIT 1" ?

Comment: Yes, infact it first order the whole table and then limit the output to one.

Answer (score 0):

As @sebas noted, it is more elegant with a view. However, I feel another implementation for the solution without creating a view would be:

```
SELECT book, COUNT(author) AS authors 
FROM BookAuthors 
GROUP BY book
HAVING authors = (
                    SELECT MAX(authors)
                    FROM 
                    (
                       SELECT book, COUNT(author) AS authors 
                       FROM BookAuthors 
                       GROUP BY book
                    ) t
                 )
```